# Horizontal Listbox item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create an horizontal ListBox item like the suggestion of the keyboard
[image]

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
          VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ListBox  Grid.Row="1"  Name="RecognizedListBox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

when I click on the button, it must show the list horizontal 
this is the code for showing the list

```
private async void RecognizeAllClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        resultword = recognizerShared.RecognizeStrokesList(InkCanvas.Children.ToList(), false);
        if (resultword.Equals(null) && resultword.Equals(""))
        {
            var messageBox = new MessageDialog("Text could not be recognized.");
            messageBox.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Close"));
            await messageBox.ShowAsync();
            resultword = null;
        }
        RecognizedListBox.ItemsSource = null;
        RecognizedListBox.ItemsSource = resultword;
    }
```

But it shows like that
[image]

After I add Height="30" to listbox, it shows me just one suggestion, and the other word none
[image]

**Solved**

```
<ListBox x:Name="RecognizedListBox" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Width="30" Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: I probably would of done it in a weird way where it's a bunch of buttons (or clickable textboxes) horizontally aligned. I never heard of a horizontal list box before.

Comment: I give an example for a listbox, maybe it will be another tool

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752289%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will help you. I never programmed for Windows phone before :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a specific size for the control so it doesn't expand

```
<ListBox  Height=30 Name="RecognizedListBox"/>
```

Or have the grid set the row height to a non `*` or `auto` sizing such

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
```

Comment: thnx, see the update 1, and I want every item near each other